# .catch does not exist on type Observable<Response>

Tags: angular

[image: .catch has an error]

[image: the 2 import statements for catch I have used but none of them is working]

I am trying to access `.catch` from service to use it as a method of **Observables** and access it in the component but it is showing error.
can somebody tell me how to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should use `catchError` with `pipe()`

```
this.http.delete().pipe(catchError(e => of(e)));
```

Comment: Observable.throw is not a function

Comment: try to use throwError instead of Observable.throw

Comment: in rxjs 6 Observable doesn't contain operators anymore

Comment: import { catchError, throwError } from 'rxjs/operators';

Comment: do i have to import throwError as well? If yes, then also its not working

Comment: if(error.status === 404)
          return throwError(new NotFoundError());

        return throwError(new AppError(error));

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182089/discussion-between-juhi-and-artyom).

Comment: you should import throwError from import { throwError } from 'rxjs';

Comment: ok cool, you can accept answer if it is working correctly now

Comment: Jesus Christ, the status of Frontend Development is a total mess